# Como usar Python para apagar todas linhas de um .txt e reescrever elas

Tags: python

A ideia é a seguinte: criei um código para que o úsuario carregue um .txt em que teremos uma informação e logo em seguida a quantidade de pontos que ela carrega, tipo assim:

```
user1 | Pontos = 30
user2 | Pontos = 22
user3 | Pontos = 11
```

Se o úsuario armazenar o valor 30 dentro da variável points_user, ele vai escrever somente as informações que conterem um valor >= 30. Porém, eu não sei como posso APAGAR todos as informações deste .txt e reescever elas de acordo com a variável points_user.

```
 print('- Deixe o .txt na mesma pasta que o executável!')
    points_user = int(input('- Filtrar por (PONTOS): '))
    
    file = Path('info.txt')
    if file.is_file():
        print('\nArquivo encontrado! :D')
        with open(file, 'r') as file:
            length_file = len(file.readlines())
        print(f'Ele tem {length_file} linhas.')
        # TXT EDIT
        info_main = list()
        with open('info.txt', 'r+') as file_main:
            for info in file_main:
                info_main.append(info)
            for position, i in enumerate(info_main):
                if int(info_main[position].split()[-1]) >= points_user:
                    file_main.write(info_main[position])
    else:
        print('Arquivo não econtrado! :(')
```

Comment: A única forma de "editar" um arquivo de texto é: abrir o arquivo em modo leitura (`r`), guardar o seu conteúdo em uma variável (string), editar/modificar o string da forma como quiser, reabrir o arquivo em modo escrita (`w`), e escrever o string modificado lá. Note que ao abrir o arquivo em modo escrita, todo o seu conteúdo é imediatamente deletado, então não tem problema de "duplicar" o que já está no arquivo.

Comment: @jfaccioni Não é a única forma. Vc pode abrir com `r` e a medida em que lê, escreve o novo conteúdo em um arquivo temporário. No final, se tudo deu certo, renomeia o arquivo temporário para o original. Isso é até melhor, porque se der algum problema na escrita, somente o arquivo temporário é afetado e o original permanece intacto. Já reabrindo o arquivo original com `w`, vc deleta o seu conteúdo, e em caso de erro na escrita, não tem como recuperar o conteúdo (supondo que o programa deu crash). Sem contar que carregar tudo pra memória não é viável para arquivos muito grandes

Answer (score 2):

Para a estrutura de arquivo apresentada na pergunta uma possibilidade de manipulação é tratá-lo, tanto para a leitura quanto para escrita, como se fosse um arquivo [CSV](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) tal que o delimitador de campos seja o caractere `|`.

A ideia então é entender o arquivo texto...

```
user1 | Pontos = 30
user2 | Pontos = 22
user3 | Pontos = 11
```

... como se fosse uma tabela...

| coluna0 | coluna1 |
| --- | --- |
| user1 | Pontos = 30 |
| user2 | Pontos = 22 |
| user3 | Pontos = 11 |

...para que então seja feito o devido tratamento e a filtragem linha a linha, e posterior retorno dos dados ao arquivo de origem.

A linguagem python possui [suporte nativo para trabalho com arquivos CSV](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/csv.html).
A função `csv.reader()` retorna um objeto leitor que irá iterar sobre as linhas no arquivo CSV fornecido. Essa função aceita como parâmetro [`delimiter`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.delimiter) uma string usada para separar campos, o padrão é `,` mas nesse caso em específico será usado o caractere `|` como argumento.

A filtragem dos dados pode ser realizada com a função embutida [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#filter) que a partir de uma função de filtragem constrói um iterador para os elementos de um iterável cujo a função retorna `True`.

Para salvar de volta no arquivo a função [`csv.writer`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/csv.html#writer-objects) retorna um objeto de escrita responsável por converter os dados em strings delimitadas.

```
import csv

dados = []                                                 #Inicia a lista que receberá os dados do arquivo.
with open('info.txt', 'rt', newline='') as f:              #Abre o arquivo como  text e para leitura....
    linhas = csv.reader(f, delimiter='|')                  #carrega as linhas do CSV onde os campos estão separados po |
    for l in linhas:                                       #Para cada linha l do CSV...
        dados.append((l[0], int(l[1].strip('Pntos= '))))   #Cria uma tupla(coluna0, o valor inteiro após Pontos = em coluna1 ) 

points_user = int(input('- Filtrar por (PONTOS): '))               #Coleta do usuário o limite para filtragem.

dados_filtrados = set(filter(lambda d: d[1]>=points_user, dados))  #Filtra as linhas cujo coluna1>=points_user

saida = [(k, f' Pontos = {v}') for (k,v) in dados_filtrados]       #Converte os dados filtrados numa lista de tuplas no formato para gravar no arquivo.

with open('info.txt', 'wt', newline='') as f:                       #Abre o arquivo no modo texto de escrita.
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)   #Obtem o objeto especializado na escrita CSV.
    writer.writerows(saida)                                         #Salva os dados filtrados de volta no aquivo.
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@Augusto-Vasques/StringAsCSV#info.txt)</sup>